# Configuring virtual network bridging through virsh

Tags: linux, bridge, libvirt

When working with libvirt to create virtual machines, I had to make guest system work in the local network as host machine does.
As it was work task, I've just googled for quick solution and set it up, but I'd like to understand, how it works under the hood.
This is the article I used as example: http://blog.leifmadsen.com/blog/2016/12/01/create-network-bridge-with-nmcli-for-libvirt/

In order to get more familiar with networking, I've read "Linux network administrator guide" and got understanding, what network bridge does - it sends packets from one LAN to another. I've read an article about linux bridges, where guy connects eth0 with eth1 through linux bridge and I believe it works.

So if I put this knowledge to my task - I have to wire vibr0 (libvirt's virtual router for virtual network) with my enp2s0f0 interface.
But when i create bridge with my hands - my PC doesn't ping any outside address.

Why the author of that article makes bridge 'primary' interface (it gets it's own IP address instead of ethernet interface) and it works but my solution - not?

Comment: please, try to show your current configuration.

Comment: @c4f4t0r did you mean configuration, I tried to create by myself?